# how to reduce social network elements loading time?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

My site has 10 articles per page and each articles has facebook like, tweet and google+ buttons and also in sidebar it has facebook like and subscribe button. These social elements take more time and increase my site loading time. Please give your advice.

Comment: Do add the `facebook` tag, so that it may go to ignore lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything to this ... The loading time of social plugins is approximately equal to (facebook example):
Your page load + Facebook call and answer time + facebook library parsing your page

So you can't do anything because you are dependant of a third party ...

The only way i know to improve the loading performance is to use the channel url like described here :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Comment: The `channelUrl` does nothing to your loading time :)

Comment: "The channelUrl points to a file that you add to your local directory which helps improve communication speed in some older browsers."<br />
Quote from : http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/

Comment: That used to benefit some aspects of it, but that is no longer the case (unless you're using IE6 with no Flash installed :/)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is use the XFBML tags, call `FB.init` with `xfbml: false`, and then *after* the page has loaded, you call `FB.XFBML.parse()`. This will effectively defer loading of the Facebook plugins until your page is done.

Now, if you want some of these rendered, earlier, then you can pass the parent node to `parse` and have only these rendered.

Alternatively, place the reference to all.js at the bottom of your DOM, and make sure you use the async pattern.